# How to change dynamic url into static url in php

Tags: php, .htaccess

I want to change my dynamic URL link into static URL link while using .haccess, its showing error 500, I have so many links with different URL links name.

```
 Options +FollowSymLinks 
 RewriteEngine on 
 RewriteRule product/categoryid/(.*)/productid/(.*)/ product.php?categoryid=$1&productid=$2
 RewriteRule product/categoryid/(.*)/productid/(.*) product.php?categoryid=$1&productid=$2
```

Comment: check the server's error logs for details about the 500.

Comment: Title of the question says that You are looking for a solution in php.

Answer (score 0):

From your question, it is assumed you're running from your domain root. As such, place the following in your `/.htaccess` file:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks 

RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^product/categoryid/(\d+)/productid/(\d+)/?$ /product.php?categoryid=$1&productid=$2 [NC,QSA,L]
```

**Changes made:**

1. I've condensed your two rules into one rule ([Don't Repeat Yourself](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Don%27t_repeat_yourself)), making the ending forward slash (`/`) optional
2. Match beginning (`^`) and end (`$`) of the expression
3. `(.*)` is now `(\d+)` which matches digits only (assumed to be IDs)
4. Added No Case (`NC`), Query String Append (`QSA`) and Last (`L`) flags to the rule

**Note:** You need to ensure that `mod_rewrite` is indeed enabled. If the 500 Internal Server Error still persists, please check your Apache logs.

Comment: is any other way to change dynamic url to static url, because .htaccess not working properly

Comment: As I said in my answer, please check your logs - there should be an error there to tell you what went wrong.